# Why is it showing only one rect for the last value of each year in my d3js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, bar-chart, bandwidth

Trying to build a bar chart and, I don't know why, it's only showing the last value for each year and not all the values in both arrays, and that's what I thought that it was supposed to happen. How can I fix that?

```js
 let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

const padding = 50;
const height = 460;
const width = 940;

 var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

var arr = [];
var years = [];
    d3.json(url, function(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = data.data[i];
            years[i] = parseInt(data.data[i][0].slice(0,4));
        }  

  const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                      .domain([0, d3.max(arr, (d) => d[1])])
                      .range([height - padding, padding]);

  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
                       .domain([d3.min(years, d => d), d3.max(years, (d) => d)])
                       .range([padding, width - padding]);

    let bandScale = d3.scaleBand().domain(years, d => d).range([padding, width - padding]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(bandScale)
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

  svg.append("g")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
       .call(xAxis);

  svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ', 0)')
      .call(yAxis)

    svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(arr)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('fill', 'blue')
        .attr('height', d => height - padding - yScale(d[1]))
        .attr('width', d => bandScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('x', (d, i) => (bandScale(years[i])))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(d[1]))
        .append('title')
        .text((d, i) => years[i] + ': ' + d[1])
    });
```

```html
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think the problem may be in your final block of code where you do the `selectAll` and `.enter().append('rect')` all in one place.  You may try using a merge so that all of the bars get the attributes you want.  e.g., set `var bars = svg.selectAll('rect').data(arr);` and then in a subsequent line, `bars.enter().append('rect').merge(bars)...`.   I think the way you have written it would have worked in v3, but not later versions.

Comment: @ekrall It didn't work. Still looks the same :T

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question.  I plotted it and saw bars for all of the years.   Is your issue that you are only seeing the last bar, or is it that you only see one bar for each year (instead of monthly)?  If it is the latter, have you tried looking into using a time scale for your x-axis?

Comment: It looks like you are parsing all of the dates into integer years, and then your x-domain is the integer years.  The result is that you are only getting one tick on the x-axis for each year